# How to make back-button work in Xamarin Live Player on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

This is specific to Xamarin and their Live Player app, specifically on Android. The soft back-button provided by the OS does also trigger the back-button provided by the Xamarin's Navigation bar - like it does when the app is deployed to the device. The navigation-related code is simple, as in this sample project: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/.

Is this by design, or am I possibly doing something wrong. I asked at forums there, but I didn't get a response. Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem? The soft back-button can't work on Android?

Comment: It doesn't trigger the back-arrow button on the navigation control, within Live Player, like it does when the app is installed.